# Does the area of $f(x,y)\lt 0$ equal $f(x,y)\le 0$?

Tags: geometry

Does the area of $f(x,y)\lt 0$ equal $f(x,y)\le 0$?

For example, the area of $x^2+y^2-1\lt 0$ and $x^2+y^2-1\le 0$ both seems to be $\pi$.

But $N(A=\left\{(x,y)|x^2+y^2-1\lt 0\right\})\lt N(B=\left\{(x,y)|x^2+y^2-1\le 0\right\})$, where $N(S)$ is the number of elements in set $S$, because $(0,1)\notin A$ and $(0,1)\in B$ and $A\subset B$.

Please clarify my confusion.

Comment: What is your domain of $x$ and $y$? Certainly, if the domain is $\mathbb{R}^2$, we should take care to note that $(0,1)\times(0,1)$ has the same cardinality as $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

Comment: You should say more about $f$. For example, if $f$ only takes the value $0$ then the area of the set where $f(x,y)<0$ is $0$ but the set where $f(x,y)\leq 0$ is the entire domain of $f$.

Comment: For the circle example we can make an [annulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_%28mathematics%29) with width $\epsilon > 0$ covering the region $f(x,y)=0$ (which here is just the unit circle). The difference between the two areas you talk about have to be smaller than the area of this annulus which is $2\pi \epsilon$. Since $\epsilon > 0$ was arbitrary the areas have to be the same. The same 'method' holds in general: if you can cover the region $f(x,y) = 0$ with something that has an area that can be made as small as possible then the two areas have to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of points (x,y) satisfying the relation $ x^2 + y^2 -1 < 0 $ is the unit disk centred at (0,0) excluding the boundary, which is the unit circle. $ x^2 + y^2 -1 \leq 0 $ is just that same set, except now including the boundary -- the unit circle.

What is the area of the unit circle? Well, the unit circle is one dimensional, it doesn't have an area. Therefore, adding it to your original set doesn't change the area, which is in both cases pi.

If you're talking about set cardinality, not area, you need to consider your domain, as the other commenters have pointed out.